# Making a div always 100% height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My problem is that I can't make the div `megrendeles_right_box` always 100% height.

I tried with `height:100%;` and `min-height:100%;`, but it's not working properly except for the padding.

Also, I wrote these styles for the body, but it's still not working.

Does this problem occur only because of using Bootstrap? I've added my styles here.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="megrendeles_main_container">
<div class="col-md-6 megrendeles_left_box">
    <form method="post">
        <h2 class="megrendeles_form_title">Személyes adatok</h2>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <span class="megrendeles_input_title">Vezetéknév *</span>
            <input required type="text" name="user_vnev" id="user_vnev" class="form-control megrendeles_input_2 input-lg" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <span class="megrendeles_input_title">Keresztnév *</span>
            <input required type="text" name="user_knev" id="user_knev" class="form-control megrendeles_input_2 input-lg" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
            <span class="megrendeles_input_title">E-mail *</span>
            <input required type="text" name="user_email" id="user_email" class="form-control megrendeles_input_2 input-lg" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
            <span class="megrendeles_input_title">Telefonszám *</span>
            <input required type="text" name="user_tel" id="user_tel" class="form-control megrendeles_input_2 input-lg" value="">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 megrendeles_right_box">

</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Some css for this:

```
.megrendeles_main_container{ width:100%;  }


.megrendeles_form_title{ padding:0 15px; display:block; margin-bottom:15px; color:#1e1e1e; font-size:22px; font-weight:700; }


.megrendeles_left_box{ background:#fff; height:100%; padding:40px; }
.megrendeles_right_box{ background:#efefef; height:100%; padding:40px; }
```

Comment: .megrendeles_main_container {
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 height: 100%;
}
add this css.

Answer (score 2):

thats because your parent div doesn't have a height. percentage is a relative quantity right?  But you can still use 100vh for full screen height

Comment: may be worth noting that, because of this, the div's 100% height = height of contents rather than parent

Comment: So what am i have to do?

Comment: @max777 i'm trying to understand what you are trying to do. can you put your code on fiddler so we can see its bahviour live and tell me what exactly you're trying to achive?. I ran the code on my end and i see a grey box underneeth the form.. so not really understand.

Comment: Green? Where? That not my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

`.megrendeles_right_box{
height:100vh;
}`

```css
 .megrendeles_main_container{ width:100%;  }


.megrendeles_form_title{ padding:0 15px; display:block; margin-bottom:15px; color:#1e1e1e; font-size:22px; font-weight:700; }


.megrendeles_left_box{ background:#fff; height:100%; padding:40px; }
.megrendeles_right_box{
   background:#efefef;
   height:100vh; /*change this*/
   padding:40px; 
   }
```

```html
<div class="megrendeles_main_container">
<div class="col-md-6 megrendeles_left_box">
    <form method="post">
        <h2 class="megrendeles_form_title">Személyes adatok</h2>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <span class="megrendeles_input_title">Vezetéknév *</span>
            <input required type="text" name="user_vnev" id="user_vnev" class="form-control megrendeles_input_2 input-lg" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <span class="megrendeles_input_title">Keresztnév *</span>
            <input required type="text" name="user_knev" id="user_knev" class="form-control megrendeles_input_2 input-lg" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
            <span class="megrendeles_input_title">E-mail *</span>
            <input required type="text" name="user_email" id="user_email" class="form-control megrendeles_input_2 input-lg" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
            <span class="megrendeles_input_title">Telefonszám *</span>
            <input required type="text" name="user_tel" id="user_tel" class="form-control megrendeles_input_2 input-lg" value="">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 megrendeles_right_box">

</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Comment: That works, but i dont know, what is vh. I will search for it.

Comment: height: 100vh = 100% of the viewport height

Comment: Its not working, if is there is to many conrent on the page, and i can scroll it vertically.